# SwiftUI's NavigationView Is Missing The Back Button On Apple Watch

Tags: swiftui, watchos, swiftui-navigationlink

I created an Apple Watch app using SwiftIU. The main view of the app is a List, with NavigationLink to another List. When I'm in one of the internal Lists, the back button isn't on the top of the view.
But when I swipe from the side of the screen (like on iOS), I go back to the main view.

Is there a way to add back the back button to the top of the screen? Is the new gesture the new "back button" for watchOS 7?

Xcode 12.2 (beta 3).
Apple Watch S6 (simulator, 7.1) and Apple Watch S5 (real, 7.0).
SwiftIU 2.0

The main view:

```swift
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(listsModel.lists) { (list) in
            NavigationLink(destination: ListView(list: list)
                            .environmentObject(list.rowsModel)) {
                ListsRowView(list: list)
            }
        }
    }
}
.onAppear {
    listsModel.update()
}
.navigationTitle("ListsView.NavigationTitle")
```

The internal view:

```swift
List(rowsModel.rows) { (row) in
    RowView(row: row, shouldUpdate: $shouldUpdate)
}
.navigationBarHidden(false)
.onAppear {
    instantiateTimer()
    rowsModel.update()
}
.onDisappear {
    cancelTimer()
}
.onReceive(timer) { _ in
    if shouldUpdate {
        rowsModel.update()
    }
}
.navigationTitle(list.name)
```

Update:
In the Canvas simulator, there is a back button, but on the regular simulator, it's not.
Canvas:

[image: Canvas]

Regular:

[image: Regular]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the NavigationView, so your code would be:

```
List {
   ForEach(listsModel.lists) { (list) in
        NavigationLink(destination: ListView(list: list)
              .environmentObject(list.rowsModel)) {
        ListsRowView(list: list)
        }
    }
}
.onAppear {
    listsModel.update()
}
.navigationTitle("ListsView.NavigationTitle")
```

The reason for this is that watchOS always has system `NavigationView` added by default

Comment: thank you for this! I was struggling to find why the navigation was broken, and removing the NavigationView from all the child views completely fixed it! :)

Comment: Remove Navigation View to actually get navigation view working... that's crazy

Comment: Thats genius... who would have thought. Good question and good answer thank you

Comment: Spent a while wondering why the default back chevron button disappeared on the pushed view. Removed the NavigationView in the root view and voila.